# Django : size of floatfields

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model with fields :

```
 PLM = models.FloatField(_('LMP'),blank=True, null=False,  default=1)
```

Is it possible in the administration interface to display 'PLM' whose size would be reduced and not as in the present case to display twenty numbers..?

Comment: what is displayed currently?

Comment: for exemple : 14.35

Comment: and what should be displayed?

Comment: It displays the result of a calculation with others fields (T/1000)*(20 +log(tr))

Comment: I'm still a little unsure about your problem. Maybe you want to provide more of your related code - e.g. your current ModelAdmin? Do you have this calculation already added somehow?

Comment: In my file admin.py, I display the fields with : list_display = ('PLM'...) and nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *only* need this in `list_display` you may do the calculation in the modeladmin as specified in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

The following snippet is taken from the docs and slightly adjusted to match your scenario.

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('calculation_plm',)

    def calculation_plm(self, obj):
        return (obj.T / 1000) * (20  + math.log(obj.tr))
    calculated_plm.short_description = 'PLM caluculation'
```

If you need this calculation more often it might be more related to the model. You can easily move it over to your model and `list_display` will also work in that case.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    PLM = models.FloatField(_('LMP'),blank=True, null=False,  default=1)

    def calculation_plm(self, obj):
        return (obj.T / 1000) * (20  + math.log(obj.tr))
    calculated_plm.short_description = 'PLM caluculation'

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('calculation_plm',)
```

Note that T and tr are not defined and i've just took them from your comment above. Of course `obj` needs this fields available to work properly.